# TinyMapper map int to subclass

Tags: c#, tinymapper

I'm using TinyMapper to map from a class `Log` to `LogViewModel`.

```
public class Log
{
  //.... bunch of properties here 
  public int LevelId {get; set;}
}

public class LogViewModel
{
  //.... bunch of properties here 
  public LogLevelViewModel Level {get; set;}
}

public class LogLevelViewModel
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

There is an enum for `Level` but we are using the view model `LogLevelViewModel` to contain the `Id` and `Name` corresponding to the enum's value and name.  In the database the `Log` has the `LevelId` field which is the enum's value.

The problem I'm having is when I try to use TinyMapper to map from `Log` to `LogViewModel`.  If I use the default binding

```
TinyMapper.Bind<Log, LogViewModel>();
```

and in the controller:

```
var data = TinyMapper.Map<List<LogViewModel>>(logs);
```

the values all populate just fine except for the `Level`, it is null even though the `Log.LevelId` is not.  When I try to map the `LevelId` to the `Level.Id` this also still just gives null for the `Level`.

```
TinyMapper.Bind<Log, LogViewModel>(config =>
{
  config.Bind(src => src.LevelId, dest => dest.Level.Id);
});
```

Ideally I need to bind from the int `LevelId` and directly populate the `Level.Id` and `Level.Name` values but if I could at least just the get the `Level.Id` value on there that would be adequate.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Side note: I did try a couple of other variations on the bindings but all I would get is an error `"System.ArgumentException: 'Expression is not a MemberExpression'"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom binder: https://github.com/TinyMapper/TinyMapper/wiki/Custom-mapping. Although then you kind of lose the point in the first place...

I'd consider AutoMapper which handles things like this quite alot more easily: https://automapper.org/

Comment: I considered it but don't think a custom binder would pass code review.  If I could use AutoMapper I would :-)  For whatever reason we only have TinyMapper in this project.